# silverlight datagrid refresh after add data from childwindow

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, datagrid

I want to refresh my datagrid after adding data from childwindow.
Below is My Home.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class Home : Page
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client webService;
        public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webService = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            webService.ReadPismaCompleted += WebService_ReadPismaCompleted;
            webService.ReadPismaAsync(0);
        }


        private void WebService_ReadPismaCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.ReadPismaCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Result != null)
            {
                dataGridPisma.ItemsSource = e.Result;

            }
        }
 private void button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ChildWindow1 childWindow = new ChildWindow1();
            childWindow.Closed += ChildWindow_Closed;
            childWindow.Show();

        }

        private void ChildWindow_Closed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
                if (( (ChildWindow1)sender).DialogResult.Value) webService.ReadPismaAsync(0);               
        }
```

I don't see any changes after adding data (click OK button on childwindow not refresh datagrid). I know that data have been added because I see that in SQL server table and also when I refresh (press F5) on my web browser I see new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `PagedCollectionView` in `WebService_ReadPismaCompleted` method

```
private PagedCollectionView _dataGridContext;

private void WebService_ReadPismaCompleted(object sender,serviceReference1.ReadPismaCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Result != null)
        {
            DataGridContext = new PagedCollectionView(e.Result)
        }
    }

  public PagedCollectionView DataGridContext
  {
     get { return _dataGridContext; }
     set { 
           _dataGridContext = value; 
           OnPropertyChanged("DataGridContext");
         }
  }
```

And set your `DataGrid.DataContext=DataGridContext`

Comment: [link to foto](http://i65.tinypic.com/wc0akm.jpg) I have some error  OnProprertyChanged

Comment: New need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your class.

Or try without call OnPropertyChanged

Comment: Can you share the new implementation ?

Comment: In with class i need to implement INOtifyPropertyChanged? In Service I have public ObservableCollection<Pismo> ReadPisma(int barkod), and my class is Pismo but i have no option to choose INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: you class Home need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` & set `this.DataContext = this;`

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
   `[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }`
```

add remove `datagridPisma.DataContext=DataGridContext`from your setter.

Comment: Now my datagrid is empty there is nothing.

Comment: share your xaml now. You should have something like `ItemsSource={Binding DataGridContext}`

Comment: I add ItemsSource as you say <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dataGridPisma" Height="695" Width="1150" ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridContext}" SelectionChanged="dataGridPisma_SelectionChanged"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"> but didn't help also I have error "the type or namespace name NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator could not be found "

Comment: remove `[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]` attribute then

Comment: put `AutoGenerateColumns=True` just to test please.

And `This.DataContext=this`

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns=True nothing change. Where put This.DataContext=this ?

Comment: In `Home`class constructor after `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: After adding This.DataContext=this  in Homeclass constructor after InitializeComponent();Error on image say: "The name 'This' doesn't exist in the current context

Comment: add it in on `ControlLoaded` event.

Comment: can you debug when your `pagedcollectionview` is updated by your web service ?

Comment: if you see nothing it's because your `pagedCollectionView` is empty

Comment: I solved the problem which was in child window, thanks for help.